# Hide Div on Desktop, Show On Mobile

Tags: css, width, screen, media, display

I have a paragraph inside a DIV that I want completely hidden when the width is > 500 and to display when the width is < 500. I'm not sure what's wrong here.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#mobileshow    { display:none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
#mobileshow   { display:block; }
}
</style>
</head>

<div id="mobileshow"><p>Click the images below to download.</p></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently my formatting was wrong. Too many spaces or line breaks in the wrong place. Not sure which. Here is the updated code:

```
<style type="text/css">
#mobileshow { 
display:none; 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
#mobileshow { 
display:block; }
}
</style>

<div id="mobileshow"><p>Click the images below to download.</p></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

do this

```
#mobileshow    { display:block; }

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    #mobileshow   { display:none; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
#mobileshow  {
display: none !important;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with display flex in your main element, don't use display block, because it breaks the styles of your element, use `display:flex`